# rollup complains apply is not exported by commonjs module that exports a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs, rollup, rollupjs

```
// main.js

import fun from './fun';

console.log(fun);
fun.func();
```

```
// fun.js

module.exports = require('./fun2').apply({ message : 'this is the message'})
```

```
// fun2.js

module.exports = function(){
  console.log(this.message)
  var inst = this ? this : {}
  inst.func = ()=>{console.log('Func was called.')}
  return inst
}
```

```
// rollup.config.js
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
const cjs = require("rollup-plugin-cjs-es");


export default {
  input: 'main.js',
  output: {
    file: 'bundle.js',
    format: 'iife'
  },
  plugins: [
    resolve(),
    commonjs({
      include: [/node_modules/]
    }),
    // cjs()
    cjs({ nested: true })
  ]
};
```

Produces the follwing bundle

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  // fun2.js

  function fun2(){
    console.log(this.message);
    return {
      func : ()=>{console.log('Func was called.');}
    }
  }

  var _require__$fun2_ = /*#__PURE__*/Object.freeze({
    __proto__: null,
    'default': fun2
  });

  // fun.js
  var fun = undefined({ message : 'this is the message'});

  // main.js

  console.log(fun);
  console.log(fun.message);

}());
```

Which is produced when the following error intermittently occurs.

```
$ ./node_modules/rollup/dist/bin/rollup -c

main.js → bundle.js...
(!) Missing exports
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#error-name-is-not-exported-by-module
fun.js
apply is not exported by fun2.js
3:
4: import * as _require__$fun2_ from "./fun2";
5: export default _require__$fun2_.apply({ message : 'this is the message'});
                                   ^
(!) Plugin rollup-plugin-cjs-es: 'fun2.js' doesn't export names expected by 'fun.js'
created bundle.js in 72ms
```

alternating the comment for cjs with and without nested : true

```
// cjs()
    cjs({ nested: true })
```

in rollup.config.js seems to reliably cause the error on first build with cjs({ nested: true }). repeated builds with cjs({ nested: true }) does not produce the same error. However in my project with third party dependencies that export in this manner -- the error happens consistently.

For some reason rollup choses to produce

```
  var _require__$fun2_ = /*#__PURE__*/Object.freeze({
    __proto__: null,
    'default': fun2
  });
```

which blows up on the function.apply

```
// fun.js
module.exports = require('./fun2').apply({ message : 'this is the message'})
//as bundle.js
  // fun.js
  var fun = undefined({ message : 'this is the message'});
```

Please help. Have struggled quite a bit finding this in this test case. My project still doesn't build since this error occurs consistently.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think 'rollup-plugin-cjs-es' and '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve' are useful.

```
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';

export default {
  input: 'main.js',
  output: {
    file: 'bundle.js',
    format: 'iife'
  },
  plugins: [
    commonjs(),
  ]
};
```

Comment: In this example no but in my project I do need them coz dependencies are npm packages.

Comment: I can't see any problem of your example. You need to post more